# Finding out what the block element <hb> is used for?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, coding-style, inline

In the book I'm using to study HTML it says and I quote "`<h1>,<h2>,<hb>,<p>, and <blockquote>`, are all block elements. But what is the block element `<hb>`? I can't find anything up on this element if its even a element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like a misprint. There's never been an `<hb>` element in HTML. What book is it?

Comment: It's called "Head First HTML and CSS", but that was my first guess because I went to google and couldn't find anything either. I wanted to reach out to a community and double check with someone else for further clarification. Thank you everyone that took the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

### There is no "block" element in HTML.

The book is referring to the default styling applied to the elements by the browser. [This article](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) explains the difference between the two types of elements (*block* and *inline*).